# How can I navigate through a 2-d array and shuffle the words within that array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I need help with this. I'm working with two-dimensional arrays and so what I'm trying to do is to navigate through the 2-d arrays in a row (starting at the top left of the array like you are reading a paragraph).
I trying to write a method that returns the array with the following rules:

1) If the word begins with a vowel (a, e, i, o, u) : swap the word with the previous word on the same row

2) If the word is the first word on the row, then swap it with the word just above it; however, if the word is on the first row, then no swapping should occur.

3) If the word begins with a consonant, then swap the first and last characters of the word.

**Ex. 2-dim array:**

rice , egg, room

apple, java, owl

**Converted:**

apple, eicr, moor

egg, owl, avaj

This is what I have so far:
*I've got the tester class all set up and ready but I having trouble setting up the methods in the class below. This is essential what I need guidance for.*

```
public class WordShuffle 
{
    // Use this method signature
    // The parameter is a 2-dim array of words
    // The method will return a 2-dim array of shuffled words

    public String[][] shuffleWords(String[][] words) 
    {


    }

}
```

Tester Class:

```
public class WordShuffleTester 
{
    // Don't change this tester except to change the values in the 2-dim array
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        // This is the 2-dim array to test your method
        String[][] words = {{ "doom", "candy", "apple"},
                          {"orange", "energy",   "rat"},
                          {   "mad",  "test",  "cool"},
                          {   "red", "blue",  "drain"}}; 

        WordShuffle shuffler = new WordShuffle();
        String[][] mixedUpWords = shuffler.shuffleWords(words);

        // The following will print out each element of the returned array
        for (int r=0; r < mixedUpWords.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c < mixedUpWords[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.print(mixedUpWords[r][c] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }



    }

}
```

If anyone could help me further with this it would be much obliged!

Comment: Smells like homework...

Answer (score 0):

I was bored enough to give this a shot, but in the future try to at least attempt to solve the problem yourself (your `shuffleWords` method was completely empty).

```
public String[][] shuffleWords(String[][] words) 
{
    String vowels = "aeiou";
    String temp = "";
    for (int i=0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < words[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(vowels.contains(words[i][j].substring(0,1)) && j > 0){
                temp = words[i][j];
                words[i][j] = words [i][j-1];
                words[i][j-1] = temp;
            }
            if(j == 0 && i > 0){
                temp = words[i][j];
                words[i][j] = words [i-1][j];
                words[i-1][j] = temp;
            }
            if(!vowels.contains(words[i][j].substring(0,1))){
                String s = words[i][j];
                temp = s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
                String first = s.substring(0,1);
                String last = s.substring(s.length()-1,s.length());
                words[i][j] = last + temp + first;
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

While this code works, it is important to note that when words are moved (due to the 1st or 2nd rule) words that begin with consonants may have the first and last letter swapped multiple times. Not sure if this is the intended effect, but some adjustments may need to be made to the order that these tasks are performed. Here is the output when I ran it using your `WordShuffleTester`

```
//Input:
doom    candy   apple
orange  energy  rat
mad     test    cool
red     blue    drain

//Output:
orange  apple   candy    
mad     mood    tar  
red     test    looc     
energy  elub    nraid
```